# Apply class to <td>

Tags: javascript, html-table

How can I find the class name of the `<p>` element contained within each `<td>` element then add that class to the `<td>` element's class list?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">
            <p class="Hello_blue">Hello Stack Overflow1</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">
            <p class="Hello_red">Hello Stack Overflow2</p>
            <p class="Hello_red">defines red color,that class want to apply to</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
            <p class="Hello_orange">Hello Stack Overflow3</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `<td>` elements would have the classes like this

```
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="blue">...</td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="red">...</td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="orange">...</td>
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and code to not use UPPERCASE.

Comment: Can you please help me,How can i reformat that code,I mean,inwhich format do you want code.,,

Comment: Thanks @humble.rumble for formatting code.

Ya I want that td should add class from <p>,same as mentioned in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the table for `p` tags, then find the closest parent `td` and assign the class name.

**Using plain Javascript:**

```
// convert "Hello_blue" to "blue"
function convertClassName(src) {
    return src.replace(/^.*?_/, "");
}

var pTags = document.querySelectorAll("table p");
for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) {
    pTags[i].parentNode.className += " " + convertClassName(pTags[i].className);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6bvwu5qL/

**Using jQuery:**

```
// convert "Hello_blue" to "blue"
function convertClassName(src) {
    return src.replace(/^.*?_/, "");
}

$("table p").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("td").addClass(convertClassName(this.className));
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/36oejbx4/

Either of these code blocks should be run after the DOM has been loaded.  That means you either place them in a script tag at the very end of the document or you call them from a function that isn't invoked until after the DOM has been loaded or you call them from an event handler (like `onload`) that waits until the DOM has been loaded.

Comment: I didn't realize until just now that you want to convert the "Hello_blue" class name to "blue" when you assign it to the parent.  I've added that part to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Select all `<p>` elements that are children of `<td>` elements, then iterate through and assign the class of each `<p>` element to its parent element.

```js
(function(){
    window.onload = function() {
        "use strict";
        var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('td p'), paragraph, i;
        for(i = 0; (paragraph = paragraphs[i]); i++) {
            paragraph.parentNode.className += paragraph.className.replace('hello_','');
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thx for ur help,but i am not able to use this code,no effect.

can you please send me complete code with its step,so that i can simply or directly run that code,and check it out...